# Installing Kibana? Having problems with ruby

Tags: installation, kibana

I am trying to download Kibana but keep getting this error? Any ideas..any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
Kibana-0.2.0$ sudo bundle install  
Fetching gem metadata from http://rubygems.org/.........  
Fetching gem metadata from http://rubygems.org/..  
Resolving dependencies...  
Installing rake (10.1.0)   
Installing daemons (1.1.9)   
Installing diff-lcs (1.1.3)   
Installing eventmachine (1.0.0)   
Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.  

/usr/bin/ruby1.9.1 extconf.rb 
/usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:45:in `require': cannot load such file -- mkmf (LoadError)
from /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:45:in  `require'
from extconf.rb:2:in `<main>'
```

Gem files will remain installed in /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/eventmachine-1.0.0 for inspection.
Results logged to /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/eventmachine-1.0.0/ext/gem_make.out

An error occurred while installing eventmachine (1.0.0), and Bundler cannot
continue.
Make sure that `gem install eventmachine -v '1.0.0'` succeeds before bundling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on your OS it might be different issues.

Suse talks about installing it through the package manager https://en.opensuse.org/User:Tsu2/Kibana

On my local dev box using Ubuntu I had to install 'rubygems' with apt to get access to 'make' and more.